# Second JAR file generated classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, netflix-dgs

I want to generate a second jar which will not contain any contents of the application but only generated classes.

I am using Netflix DGS and it has a plugin which generates the classes from schema. I want to create a dependency containing these classes and use them in another service.

Can you please provide a Maven code which will generate such thing?

I have tried multiple things (shade, assembly), but everytime I get an exception that package doesn't exist. I have also checked classpathes and etc. and everything seems fine

Comment: Please show the efforts you already tried... also the structure of your project, which JDK, Maven version etc. you are using...